# What is the smallest manned jet aircraft?

Tags: aviation-history, jet

In the movie [Spy Kids (2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0227538/?ref_=nv_sr_1), there is a scene where the characters board a small jet aircraft "built for one passenger". The aircraft is about 2 meters tall with a 3 meters wingspan, and features a single jet engine, air intake located below the canopy, and tricycle landing gear.

[image]

Which got me wondering: *what is the smallest fixed-wing jet-powered aircraft to date?*

Some clarifications:

- The aircraft must be able to takeoff and land under its own power (i.e. aircraft [launched mid-air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yokosuka_MXY-7_Ohka) does not count).
- The aircraft is propelled by one or more turbojet or turbofan engine(s) (i.e. no propellers, no rockets).
- "Smallest" is measured by wing span.
- The aircraft must be pilot operated (i.e. RC aircraft does not count).
- This is not a question about whether an aircraft that small is possible, since there is already another [very similar question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/45911/could-this-wingless-dodo-fly-in-real-life). Rather, this question is about the smallest aircraft successfully flown in history to date.

Comment: That could be something like a [coléoptère](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42771/3201), if you focus on the wing span.

Comment: The title is a bit confusing. A UAV is still "pilot-operated". Perhaps "manned" is more appropriate.

Comment: +1 for giving a clear definition what "smallest" should mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer, but the [jet variant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azEPrrRRTY0) of the [Colomban Cri-cri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colomban_Cri-cri) will probably be tough to beat. According to Wikipedia, its wingspan is 4.9 m (16 ft 1 in).

[image]

Comment: Probably a close second would be the [Sonex Aircraft Subsonex](http://www.sonexaircraft.com/subsonex/), with an 18' wingspan.

Comment: Photo http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/538184554_1280x720.jpg

Comment: @RonBeyer - The BD-5J has a 17' wingpsan.

Answer (score 19):

The [BD-5J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bede_BD-5) is what guinness world records claims to be the smallest but it is larger than the Cri-Cri in its jet implementation (the BD-5A is smaller than the Cri-Cri but prop powered)

If you want to count really experimental stuff the [Martin Marietta X-24A lifting body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Marietta_X-24) has a wingspan of only 11 ft 6in. making it the smallest. Although I will admit it is predicated on a lose definition of ["wing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wing) and is rocket (not jet) powered.

Although if you [broaden your definition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2sT9KoII_M) of "aircraft" [Yves Rossy's jet wing backpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yves_Rossy) is the smallest coming in at a wingspan of 7.9 ft. It is still piloted, jet powered although I do not think it can take off under its own power.

Comment: Great answer, but I think the BD-5A is a pusher prop. The jet variant is BD-5J.

Comment: @FredLarson Interesting, i did not know that ill modify to reflect. I see the 5B listed as a piston plane but cant really find much on the 5A

Comment: Second paragraph of the article: "The BD-5 has a small, streamlined fuselage holding its semi-reclined pilot under a large canopy, with the engine installed in a compartment in the middle of the fuselage, and a propeller-driving engine - or jet engine in the BD-5J variant"

Comment: Just found it hahah.

Comment: Also note the photo caption: "BD-5J N3038V, **Guinness record holder for the world's smallest turbojet-powered manned aircraft.**"

Comment: I saw another article noting that as well. Its also what comes up if you search "smallest jet aircraft"

Comment: OP did say no rocket powered craft.  X-24A has a rocket engine.  Also, not sure it could take-off on its own - think it was always dropped.

Comment: The jet wing backpack was the first thing that popped into my mind, too. I discounted it for the same reason you did. Though I hear he's working on a version that can launch itself.

Comment: Neither of these seem to be able to take off under their own power

Comment: [EM-10 Bielik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marga%C5%84ski_%26_Mys%C5%82owski_EM-10_Bielik) has wingspan only 10 cm longer.

Comment: Regarding Yves' jetpack: in Britain it is not considered an aircraft but rather an aircraft component. As parts of Yves' body act as control surfaces **he had to register himself as an airplane**, though common sense prevailed and he was exempted from the seatbelt law.

Comment: I can attest that this is a hilarious little jet.  Saw Bob Bishop himself fly one at an airshow in the '90s sometime and got to meet him afterwards - talk about a guy with passion.  Given the number of these things that have killed their pilots you kind of have to be a bit mad to get into one.  Bishop himself later (luckily) managed to bail out of one that caught fire midair.  Canada lost our only BD-5 pilot about a decade ago when his wing fell off during flight practice in Ottawa.

Comment: BD-5J in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlBUPtKIoHo

Answer (score 4):

The [Bede BD-5J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bede_BD-5) is smallest according to Guinness.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best answer?  The Bell Rocket Belt.

Developed in the late 1960s, it used a Williams jet engine and could provide up to 20 minutes of flight at speeds as high as 85 mph.  The Army has evaluated it but eventually declined to purchase it and the project was dropped.